# Voltage Regulation: How do I work out the required resistance?

Tags: voltage-regulator, zener

Outline:
I have available a 12 V power supply rated at 50 W maximum.
I need to power a device which takes 4.5 V at a maximum of 1.5 A.
I plan to use a Zener/transistor schematic.

Question: Given the schematics below, how do I work out what value the resistor should be?
Side question: How do I work out the power (in watts) that will go through the resistor and Zener?

edit: Also, should the schematic be preceded by a resistor?

Schematic:

[image: zener/transistor voltage regulator]

edit2: Here is a proposed switching regulator to replace the above schematic:

[image: switching regulator]

edit3: I have successfully made a 5.1v regulator (well 5.03v, but there is room for a small amount of error) (i could only do 5.1 as per the components i have to hand), here are the schematics:

[image: voltage regulator]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102292/discussion-on-question-by-equave-voltage-regulation-how-do-i-work-out-the-requi). Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Answer (score 4):

Don't.

A Zener + Transistor really isn't a sensible power supply. Get an adjustable voltage regulator.

As this is really a use case for a switch-mode supply, there's no appropriate resistance.

Generally, you want the base current to be so that V_CE is exactly 12V-4.5V, and you'll have to consult your transistor datasheet's curves for that. Datasheets are different. But, due to different load and temperature behaviour of the transistor's Base-Emitter junction and the Zener junction, this really isn't a stable regulator, and I honestly wouldn't know myself how to optimally dimension Zener and resistor (there's more that matters about the Zener diode than its Zener voltage) to make this the least terrible. It'll probably remain a terrible regulator.

Seriously, this is 2019, not 1962. You can buy linear regulators for very little money, when you have a use case for them; this isn't one.

In your use case, get a buck converter, not a linear regulator (like the one you're trying to build in a bad way, here), otherwise you'll be burning (12V-4.5V)·1.5A = 11.25 W in that regulator, which will be impossible to keep cool enough.

A linear supply, built from scratch like yours, or bought as way better and cheaper component, won't work; assuming you have a relatively well-coolable transistor (read the transistor datasheet, look for "thermal resistance") with say 10 K/W, that transistor will still get 110 °C hotter than ambient temperature from the 11 W and burn.

Comment: Would the switching regulator added in edit2 be appropriate and fix the issue you uncovered?

Comment: no, that is not a swtiching regulator, at all. Stop copying random circuits from random places. Learn to understand what I said: your second circuit still burns all the voltage difference in the top transistor and hence still won't work.

Comment: @equave The second circuit is even worse than the first

Comment: thanks for tips on how to improve it.